# Job Status: job incurred error

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I was checking the limits of shots in IBMQ at the time of execution of the circuit so I was getting this error message `Job Status: job incurred error` at `shots = 9000` what does it mean is there any limit at the no. of shots or it just some module failure

Comment: If you run your algorithm in Composer, you can choose 1, 1024, 4096 or 8192 shots. So, it seems that there is a upper limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit for shots on devices is 8192. For simulators it is much higher.